# Pycharm crashes java on installing

Tags: linux, java

Am trying to install pycharm using the pycharm/bin/pycharm.sh and located it in /usr/bin/share on Linux mint 18(32 bit) and this is the error that am getting, i have installed both openjdk-9-jdk and openjdk-9-jre. I have no idea whats going wrong. Any help would be highly appreciated and thanks in advance.

```
WARN: Unknown class loader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader
WARN: Unknown class loader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$PlatformClassLoader
WARN: Unknown class loader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader
WARN: Unknown class loader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$PlatformClassLoader
Jul 15, 2017 3:18:44 PM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$6 run
WARNING: Prefs file removed in background /root/.java/.userPrefs/prefs.xml

Start Failed: Internal error. Please report to http://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors

com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.a(PluginManager.java:94)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@9-internal/Thread.java:804)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@9-internal/Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-internal/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-internal/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@9-internal/Method.java:531)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.a(PluginManager.java:91)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.intellij.util.concurrency.AppScheduledExecutorService$Holder
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.AppScheduledExecutorService.getInstance(AppScheduledExecutorService.java:50)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.AppExecutorUtil.getAppScheduledExecutorService(AppExecutorUtil.java:39)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.AppExecutorUtil.getAppExecutorService(AppExecutorUtil.java:53)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor.<clinit>(PooledThreadExecutor.java:32)
    at com.intellij.ide.a.m.u.<init>(u.java:63)
    at com.intellij.ide.a.e.b.<init>(b.java:23)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.a(MainImpl.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@9-internal/Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-internal/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-internal/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@9-internal/Method.java:531)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.access$000(MainImpl.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@9-internal/Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-internal/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-internal/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@9-internal/Method.java:531)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1.start(MainImpl.java:48)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareAndStart(StartupUtil.java:147)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@9-internal/Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-internal/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-internal/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@9-internal/Method.java:531)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:40)
    ... 6 more

#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xb65e2e48, pid=2734, tid=2753
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (9.0) (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195526.buildd.src)
# Java VM: OpenJDK Server VM (9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195526.buildd.src, mixed mode, tiered, concurrent mark sweep gc, linux-x86)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libjava.so+0x18e48]  JNU_GetEnv+0x18
#
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /root/java_error_in_PYCHARM_2734.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Aborted
```

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm does not support JDK **9** because it is unstable. Try JDK **8**.

Answer (score 0):

Try with real JDK from Orcale, not OpenJDK (as you can see in the error message it is a bug in the latter one). With luck an older OpenJDK will do, but in my experience the OpenJDK's in general have often problems, so jsut stick to Oracle JDK (unfortunately).

Comment: JetBrains supports OpenJDK. They even ship patched version of OpenJDK with their products. PyCharm should work both with OpenJDK and OracleJDK, but only 8 is supported while topic starter uses 9.